# Required properties on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to find out if two required properties are found in array of objects, I need a boolean that says true if at least those items are found and false if any of them is missing, any other properties are not an issue for the boolean as long as those two required properties are there.

So I got this, but I don't know how to produce a true boolean when both files are included

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'required1'
  },
  {
    name: 'noRequired'
  },
  {
    name: 'required2'
  },
  {
    name: 'noRequired'
  },
]

const required = ['required1', 'required2']

const result = data.filter(({ name }) => !required.includes(name))


console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I have tried some and every but it does not work as it has to be the two included in the array as in 'every' but not the rest in the array as in 'some'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`every` does work, but you have to create a new array of names, and then check to see if those names are included in your `required` list. You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over an array of objects to create an new array of names and use that for a comparison.

```js
const data=[{name:"required1"},{name:"noRequired"},{name:"required2"},{name:"noRequired"}];

const required = ['required1', 'required2'];

const values = data.map(obj => obj.name);

const result = required.every(name => {
  return values.includes(name);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this approach but why not just do `const values = data.map(({name}) => name)`? and then just `const result = required.every(name => values.includes(name))`

Comment: yeah, `data` is an array so `Object.values(data)` gives a shallow copy of the array which makes no use here.

Comment: Sorry! I've been up all night. You're both right. Sometimes I'm a moron.

Answer (score 3):

```
function containsAll(needles, haystack){ 
  for(var i = 0; i < needles.length; i++){
     if($.inArray(needles[i], haystack) == -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

containsAll([34, 78, 89], [78, 67, 34, 99, 56, 89]); // true
containsAll([34, 78, 89], [78, 67, 99, 56, 89]); // false
containsAll([34, 78, 89], [78, 89]); // false
```

Comment: It does not work, if you remove `required2` from data you still get true

Comment: you need to check if required array data available or not in data array right ?? so if `required2` remove  then  `required1` is still available in data's array
and you can use here forEach loop also instead of filter

Comment: `['required1', 'required2' ]` both need to be there, if so is `true`, regardless of the orher values. If any of those strings are missing, it should be false.

Comment: okk got you wait i'll do some changes in code

Comment: please use now if still not working then tell me

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the difference between 2 arrays (`required` - `data`) and if the `length` is `0` then `true` else `false`

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'required1'
  },
  {
    name: 'noRequired'
  },
  {
    name: 'required2'
  },
  {
    name: 'noRequired'
  },
]

const required = ['required1', 'required2']

const names = data.map(m => m.name);
const result = !required.some(f => !names.includes(f));

// Alternative -
//const diffCount = required.filter(f => !names.includes(f)).length;
//const result = diffCount == 0;


console.log(result)
```

Comment: `!some(!condition)` is the same as `every(condition)`

Comment: @marzelin, yes I realize that now.